# Auto scroll to a particular option in the Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Suppose I have a list of items in the dropdown or `Autocomplete` in Material-UI, how can one auto-scroll to the desired item in the list when I just tap on the drop down, for example in the list of `top100Films`, I already have the items, meaning when I open the dropdown, it first shows:

```
{ label: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 }
```

What I want to achieve is, when I open the dropdown the list of items should start at an Item I want e.g:

```
{ label: 'Inception', year: 2010 }
```

*Should appear as the first, but the list of the dropdown should auto-scroll to that item.*

Below is the entire code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { label: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  ...
];
```

How best can this be achieved?

Comment: Does this statement, "Should appear as the first, but the list of the dropdown should auto-scroll to that item." mean that you want the list to appear normally and then scroll down to the item?

Comment: Yes @ShamarYarde, thats what I meant

Comment: The list should remain in it's order, but it should auto scroll to the desired Item (Like auto scrolling)

Comment: Hi @ShamarYarde, do you have any clue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scroll to the option, you need to identify the equivalent element on the DOM tree, then call `Element.scrollIntoView()`.

You can do that by attaching a data attribute to each option element using `renderOption`, then every time the user opens, use `document.querySelector()` to find the option based on the attribute and scroll to it:

```
<Autocomplete
  onOpen={() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const optionEl = document.querySelector(
        `[data-name="${movieToScrollTo}"]`
      );
      optionEl?.scrollIntoView();
    }, 1);
  }}
  renderOption={(props, option) => {
    return (
      <li {...props} data-name={option.label}>
        {option.label}
      </li>
    );
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Why does this scrolls the entire page in React.js ?